# Installed vm debian gnu linux 10, trying to format/erase/fix a read only sd card in a linux way that windows or mac won't do?

Tags: debian, command-line, gparted, sd-card, file-format

I've installed Debian GNU Linux 10 in a VM. I'm trying to format/erase/fix a read only SD Card in a Linux way that Windows or Mac won't do.

Unfortunately I don't know anything about linux/cli, but what commands can I do in linux? `gparted`/`sm`?

wanted to try `sm` as was advised by someone but it says that command is not recognized?

I confirmed the adapter switch is unlocked, I tried through a usb dongle without any adapter switch, my old phone turned 2 sd cards into read only and everything I've tried on them in windows or mac (all the usual advice) says read only error.

Before I smash them with a hammer, I want to try something on linux to completely erase/zero it etc, in case it has any special tools other os don't have.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the SD card is not locked in a read-only mode or that the port/adapter is a read writable one?  Before moving forward please confirm this information and edit your post to include the steps you have taken, and exactly what you wish to accomplish. Please visit the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about how to post and use this site. Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep I updated the post to include more information.